# Running UWP app from Command Line is "ONLY" showing the splash screen of the app

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I'm using [Launch UWP App Via CommandLine](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/launch-uwp-app-via-commandline/) online tutorial to execute my `UWP` app named `UWPTest` via `PowerShell` on `Windows 10 -latest version update 1903`. The app opens successfully but only shows the splash screen. Moreover, the splash screen just stays there forever unless I close it using `X` button on top right corner. **Question**: What could be the cause and how can we resolve it?

**Note**:

1. The splash screen does not hang it just stays there and I can move it around, maximize, minimize, etc.
2. When I ran the app from start menu it works as expected and shows the following Main Page.
3. Ref: [uap5:AppExecutionAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-appexecutionalias)

**Snapshot of Splash Screen** [that just stays there when running the app via command line]:

[image]

**Snapshot of Main Window of the app** [that appears normally if run the app from `VS2019` or from the windows Start Menu. But this window does now appear when running the app via command line]:

[image]

**My appxmanifest File of UWPTest app**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5">

  <Identity
    Name="86754353-ac66-48f5-b6bb-fdad292dd398"
    Publisher="CN=myDesktopUserName"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="86754353-ac66-48f5-b6bb-fdad292dd398" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>UWPTest</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>myDesktopUserName</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="UWPTest.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="UWPTest"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="UWPTest"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" ShortName="MyTestApp" Square71x71Logo="Assets\SmallTile.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\LargeTile.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo"/>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo"/>
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile >
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias" Executable="UWPTest.exe" EntryPoint="UWPTest.App">
          <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
            <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="UWPTest.exe"/>
          </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
        </uap5:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

**UPDATE**:

1. A copy of the project is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02184729165177016030) if you want to test it on your own. It's a very basic `Hello World` type project - nothing fancy. If you like, you can make any changes to make it work and then let me your suggestion.
2. to clarify further: The app runs successfully when launching from start menu or from `VS2019`. But, as suggested [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/#UBVMcO4PxzD2OSaV.97), when I add `OnActivated(…)` method in `App.xaml.cs` to make it run from command line, it shows only `Splash Screen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to note, that when `OnActivated` is executed, the `OnLaunched` method is not. You must make sure to initialize the application the same way as you do in the `OnLaunched` method.

First - do not remove the `OnLaunched` method - that will make the app impossible to debug from Visual Studio, so uncomment it.

Next, `OnActivated` method needs to initialize the frame if it does not yet exist (app is not already running) and navigate to the first page. Also - use `ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch` to recognize that the app has been launched from the command line. Finally, activate the `Window.Current` instance. I have downloaded your sample and tested to confirm this code works.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

        //Navigate to main page
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }

    //Command line activation
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch)
    {
        var commandLineArgs = args as CommandLineActivatedEventArgs;

        //Read command line args, etc.
    }

    //Make window active (hide the splash screen)
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me - specially outlining the logic behind your code.. It worked like a charm. Also, after bringing `OnLaunched` method (and adding your code for `OnActivated`) app now works with both with and without command line (i.e, from Start Menu and from VS2019, as well).

Answer (score 1):

> Running UWP app from Command Line is “ONLY” showing the splash screen of the app

The app will trigger `OnActivated` method when you launch app with command line, you need to  invoke `Window.Current.Activate();` method in OnActivated override function and navigate the specific page base on the parameter.  Please use the following to replace yours.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{

    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        // Navigate to a view 
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        // assuming you wanna go to MainPage when activated via protocol
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs);

    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: In `Application.xaml.cs` class, I replaced the method `OnLaunched` with your suggested `OnActivated` method (with the code you suggested) but command line is still opening the splash screen only.

Comment: I've added an `UPDATE` section on my post above and has provided a link to a copy of the project - just in case you want to see my real code